# How to "properly" handle $_GET variables in PHP?

Tags: php, validation, variables, get

Currently, I have the following code:

```
if(isset($_GET['mid']) && !empty($_GET['mid'])) {
    $mid = $_GET['mid'];

    if(is_numeric($mid) && $mid > 0) {
        if(isset($_GET['op']) && !empty($_GET['op'])) {
            $op = $_GET['op'];

            if($op == 'info') {
            }

            if($op == 'cast') {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I think it's too "complex" with if statements inside if statements, etc...

Would you handle it differently? How would you make it simpler?

Comment: First of all, make your code just sensible. `if(is_numeric($mid) && $mid > 0) {` => `if(is_numeric($mid))`, `if(isset($_GET['mid']) && !empty($_GET['mid']))` => `if(!empty($_GET['mid']))` and so on. See http://php.net/empty

Comment: I didn't know `is_numeric()` returned false for `0`. The other one I didn't know either.

Comment: It doesn't. [`is_numeric()`](http://php.net/is_numeric) returns `TRUE` on `0`. You can collapse `isset()` into `!empty()`, however.

Comment: @Mark Trapp:  Tell that to 40% of the answerers.

Comment: is_numeric doesn't but you have **already** checked for 0 with empty(), so, no additional  $mid > 0 required

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would use [filter_input](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php) with the FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT filter for mid. Something like that :

```
$mid = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'mid', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT);
$op = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'op');
if($mid > 0){
  switch($op){
    case 'info':
      // Some code
      break;
    case 'cast':
      // Some more code
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: This has a problem:  If `$_GET['op']` contains the string `info`, your switch block will run all of the code in every case.  You should add breaks.

Comment: @Mark ehh...  Didn't think of that.

Answer (score 6):

I'd write a function that would take the name of the index, and either return the value within `$_GET` or throw an exception.

That, or encapsulate it in a class similar to the following:

```
#$_GET = array('name' => 'Ignacio', 'foo' => '42');

class Get
{
  public static function string($name)
  {
    if (isset($_GET[$name]))
    {
      return $_GET[$name];
    }
    else
    {
      throw new Exception(sprintf('Unknown GET parameter "%s"', $name));
    }
  }

  public static function int($name)
  {
    $val = Get::string($name);
    $ret = filter_var($val, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
    if ($ret != $val)
    {
      throw new Exception(sprintf('Invalid int GET parameter "%s"', $name));
    }
    return $ret;
  }
}

echo Get::string('name') . "\n";
echo Get::int('foo') . "\n";
#echo Get::int('name') . "\n";
#echo Get::int('age') . "\n";
```

Comment: Could you give an example on that class approach?

Comment: fairly nice, though using static isn't as "nice" or reusable for _POST

Comment: @zanlok: Passing an array to the constructor is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: your answer doesn't have the same approach; it's fundamentally different. overly defensive?

Comment: I wonder what would happen if you do this;
`echo GET::int('hour')`
when your url is like;
`?hour=0`

Answer (score 4):

1. `empty` already checks if a variable `isset`.
2. `is_numeric` is a bit verbose, since you are also checking against `0`.
3. A switch statement is best suited for checking variables against multiple string values

I would do this:

```
$mid = empty($_GET['mid']) ? 0 : (int)$_GET['mid'];
                                 // casting as an integer will
                                 // make undesirable strings = 0

if ($mid > 0 && !empty($_GET['op'])) {
    switch($_GET['op']) {
        case 'info':
            break;
        case 'cast':
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

If you need to store `$_GET['op']` in a variable for later, you could do so prior to the switch block, though I wouldn't unless it was needed.

Answer (score 3):

I like the idea of creating an InputFilter class which implements ArrayAccess. This is more object oriented and more customizeable, since you can add methods at whim for customization, and be working with the same main filterizing object.

```
$get = new InputFilter($_GET);
echo $get->value_integer('variable_name');
```

What's also nice about this is that it's reusable for $_POST, etc. You'd just need to do something like `$post = new InputFilter($_POST);`. And, you can use it for other sources of input as well.

Or, if you have a new enough version of php, you could implement filter_input() later on as well, as suggested by @Arkh. IMO, having your own class feels a lot more reusable and durable.

```
<?php

// empty for now, fill in later if desired
class InputFilterException extends Exception {}

/*
 * Use the ArrayAccess interface as a template.
 *
 * Usage examples:
 *    $controller->get = InputFilter($_GET);
 *    echo $controller->get->value_string_html('variable');
 *    $controller->post = InputFilter($_POST);
 *    echo $controller->get->value_integer('variable');
 */
class InputFilter implements ArrayAccess {

    protected $data;

    function __construct( $data ) {
        if( !is_array($data) ) {
            throw new InputFilterException ("Only arrays are allowed here");
        }
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    // do not actually use these
    function __get( $offset ) {
        throw new InputFilterException( "Don't use as an array, use functions ->string() ->int() etc: ['" . $offset . "']" );
    }
    function __set( $offset, $value ) {
        throw new InputFilterException( "Don't modify directly: ['" . $offset . "'] = \"" . $value . "\"" );
    }

    // implement ArrayAccess

    function offsetExists( $offset ) {
        return isset( $this->data[$offset]) );
    }

    function offsetSet( $offset, $value ) {
        $this->data[$offset] = $value;
    }

    function offsetUnset( $offset ) {
        unset( $this->data[$offset] );
    }

    function offsetGet( $offset ) {
        throw new InputFilterException ("Don't use this object as an array, but were an array : ". $offset);
    }

    protected function getValue( $offset ) {

        if( is_array($this->data[$offset]) ) {
            throw new InputFilterException ("must use the asArray() function");
        }
        return $this->data[$offset];
    }

    function data_count() {
        return count($this->data);
    }

    public function set_value( $offset, $data ) {
        $this->offsetSet( $offset, $data );
    }

    // get an array *in* the data
    public function asArray($offset) {

        if( !is_array ($this->data[$offset]) ) {
            throw new InputFilterException("only use asArray() for arrays");
        }
        return new Filter( $this->data[$offset] );
    }

    // validators...

    function is_set( $offset ) {
        return $this->offsetExists($offset);
    }

    function is_empty( $offset ) {
        return $this->is_set($offset) && strlen($this->data[$offset]) == 0;
    }

    function is_numeric( $offset ) {
        return $this->is_set($offset) && is_numeric($this->data[$offset]);
    }

    function is_integer( $offset ) {

        if( !$this->is_set($offset) ) {
            return false;
        } elseif( is_numeric($this->data[$offset]) ) {
            $int_value = intval($this->data[$offset]);
            return $int_value == $this->data[$offset];
        } elseif( strlen($this->data[$offset]) == 0 ) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    function is_array( $offset ) {
        return $this->is_set($offset) && is_array($this->data[$offset]);
    }

    // return data formatted

    function value_string( $offset ) {
        return $this->getValue($offset);
    }

    function value_string_html( $offset ) {
        return htmlentities( $this->getValue($offset), null, 'UTF-8' );
    }

    function value_integer( $offset ) {
        return intval( trim($this->getValue ($offset)) );
    }

    function value_numeric( $offset ) {
        return doubleval($this->getValue ($offset));
    }

    function value_alphanumeric( $offset ) {
        return preg_replace("*[^A-Za-z0-9]*", "", $this->getValue ($offset));
    }

    function value_unfiltered( $offset ) {
        return $this->getValue( $offset );
    }

}

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could make a helper function:

```
function getvar($var) {
    return isset($_GET[$var]) && !empty($_GET[$var]) ? $_GET[$var] : false;
}

$mid = getvar('mid');
$op = getvar('op');

if(is_numeric($mid) && $mid > 0) {
    if($op == 'info') {
    }

    if($op == 'cast') {
    }
}
```

That would make your code a bit cleaner, but you code itself is allright.

Comment: Checking if a variable `isset` and/or `empty` is redundant.  `empty` already checks if it is set.

Answer (score 2):

What you could do is define a filter function (which already exists in PHP >= 5.2) which would filter a variable based on an argument on what type it is, whether it is a number, a string, or more depending on your requirements.

```
function myfilter($variable, $type) {
    switch($type){
        case 'numeric':
        //check for numbers
        return the number or false based on check
        break;
        case 'alphanumberic':
        //check for alphanumeric
        return the text or false based on check
        break;
    }
}
```

Then use this function to filter the values that you get using $_GET

```
$foo = myfilter($_GET['foo'], 'numeric');
$bar = myfilter($_GET['bar'], 'alphanumeric');
```

Comment: Actually it exists in PHP >= 5.2

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like the below. More-or-less. But you can also use filter for much of these things. And you can also turn off warnings and just use empty() and not worry about isset in the first chunk.

```
function checkVar($var)
{
    if(isset($var) && !empty($var)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

function checkID($id){
    if(checkVar($id) && is_numeric($id) && $id > 0) {
        return $id;
    }
    return false; 
}

if($mid = checkID($_GET['mid'])) {
    if(checkVar($_GET['op'])) {
        switch($_GET['op']) {
            case 'info':
            break;

            case 'cast':
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Checking if a variable `isset` and/or not `empty` is redundant. `empty` already checks if it is set.

Comment: @Stephen: http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php Not according to the docs. Which means it would toss a warning. Maybe you have warnings turned off and you've never seen it.

Comment: Tsk. Tsk.  Check your facts.  This is from the page you referenced:  "empty() is the opposite of (boolean) var, except that no warning is generated when the variable is not set."

Comment: Then someone should add that to the list of return value conditions. Sometimes I really hate PHP's inconsistent documentation. But no need to be snotty.

Answer (score 0):

It looks a bit complex. But it appears you want to test for an awful lot of edge conditions. However, there are ways to unify the process. I'm using a [wrapper class](http://sourceforge.net/p/php7framework/wiki/input/) for that:

```
if ($_GET->int["mid"]) {
if ($_GET->in_array("op", "info,cast")) {
```

But one could define a custom method which combines all the isset and is_numeric or whatever checks.

Comment: That overloads the `$_GET` superglobal?  Not nice!

Comment: @Stephen: It does. Semantics are close. But if you like complexity, you can also define wrapper objects: `$getVars = new input($_GET)` yikes.

Comment: I don't know why this was downvoted.  I may not agree with the recommended implementation, but it is still a valid strategy.  +1 for balance.

Comment: @Stephen: I might have downvoted it too, since it's a bit overkill for what the OP wants. But it's an option nevertheless and does indeed simplify things - once you befriend or extend the API.

Answer (score 0):

I like that following approach for integer variables:

```
private function _extract_int_val($val) {
    if ( isset($val) ) {
        $number = esc_sql($val);
        if ( is_numeric($number) && $number >= 0) {
            return (int) $number;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There's nothing wrong with this. Nested if statements are absolutely okay.
You could use [filter](http://php.net/filter) though.

Comment: Yes, the question was more about "code complexity" in terms of how it looks. I normally tend to have lines as long as 80chars and with lots of nested if statements, the "real code" will have little breathing space.

Comment: Well, for starters, empty already checks if a variable isset.